# Jaxb Unmarshaller handles Long and Integer differently

Tags: jaxb2, unmarshalling

I have a class with a single Long variable which I want my input xml to be unmarshalled to. When I run unmarshal (unit test attached) I get the following error thrown in the ValidationEventHandler

```
[severity=ERROR,message=For input string: "",locator=node=null,object=null,url=null,line=1,col=96,offset=-1]]
LinkedException: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
```

The class and unit tests look like this -

```
@XmlRootElement
    public class Annotation {

    private Long creatorNo;

    public Long getCreatorNo() {
        return creatorNo;
    }

    public void setCreatorNo(Long creator) {
        creatorNo = creator;
    }
}
```

Unit test -

```
public class AnnotationTest {

    @Test
    public void testUnmarshall() throws Exception {
        final String inputXML = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><annotation><creatorNo></creatorNo></annotation>";
        final JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Annotation.class);
        final Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxbContext.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new UnmarshallerValidationEventHandler());
        final Annotation annotationObject = (Annotation)unmarshaller.unmarshal(new StringReader(inputXML));
    }
}
```

From what it looks like, Jaxb didn't like being passed an empty element to an type of Long. However now if I change the type of the 'creatorNo' to Integer instead of Long in the 'Annotation' class, there are no exceptions thrown and Jaxb will just create the class with the 'creatorNo' set to 0. So why this different behavior?

The real behavior I am after is that I want Jaxb to treat the 'creatorNo' as optional and set it to NULL for and empty XML element. Is this possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Note:**  I'm the [**EclipseLink JAXB (MOXy)**](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/moxy.php) lead and a member of the [**JAXB 2 (JSR-222)**](http://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=222) expert group.

The issue you are seeing converting an empty element to a `Long` is a JAXB RI issue and not a JAXB issue as other implementations such as MOXy handle this use case correctly.  You can log a bug against the JAXB RI at the following location:

- http://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB/

**Workarounds**

1. Use another implementation of JAXB (JSR-222) without this issue, this option is a big benefit of coding to a standard API.
2. If you use the default `ValidationEventHandler` this conversion exception will be ignored and your document will unmarshal as expected.
3. Use an `XmlAdapter` to convert between a `String` and `Long` yourself.  You can leverage JAXB's `DatatypeConverter` to make this easier.
4. Change your implementation of `UnmarshallerValidationEventHandler` to be more tolerant of conversion errors.

**UnmarshallerValidationEventHandler**

```
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEvent;
import javax.xml.bind.ValidationEventHandler;

public class UnmarshallerValidationEventHandler implements ValidationEventHandler {

    @Override
    public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
        return event.getSeverity() < ValidationEvent.FATAL_ERROR;
    }

}
```